# Python CSV - Writing different lists in the same CSV-file

Tags: python-3.x, csv

**SEE UPDATE BELOW!**

For my Python program I need to write 3 different lists to a csv file, each in a different column. Each lists has a different size.

```
l1 = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
l2 = ['11', '22', '33', '44']
l3 = ['111', '222', '333']
f = 'test.csv'
outputFile = open(f, 'w', newline='')
outputWriter = csv.writer(resultFile, delimiter=';')
outputWriter.writerow(headerNames)
for r in l3:
    resultFile.write(';' + ';' + r + '\n')
for r in l2:
    resultFile.write(';' + r + '\n')
for r in l1:
    resultFile.write(r + '\n')
resultFile.close()
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. The values of the lists are written below each other list in the column to the right. I would prefer to have the list values written beside one another just like this:

```
1;11;111
2;22;222
etc.
```

I am sure there is an easy way to get this done, but after hours of trying I still cannot figure it out.

**UPDATE:**

I tried the following. It is progress, but I am still not there yet.

```
f = input('filename: ')
l1 = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
l2 = ['11', '22', '33', '44']
l3 = ['111', '222', '333']
headerNames = ['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3']
rows = zip(l1, l2, l3)
with open(f, 'w', newline='') as resultFile:
    resultWriter = csv.writer(resultFile, delimiter=';')
    resultWriter.writerow(headerNames)
    for row in rows:
        resultWriter.writerow(row)
```

It write the data in the format I would like, however the values 4, 5 and 44 are not writen.

Comment: check out `itertools.zip_longest`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first attempt is not using the csv module properly, nor transposing the rows like your second attempt does.

Now zipping the rows will stop as soon as the shortest row ends. You want `itertools.ziplongest` instead (with a fill value of 0 for instance)

```
import itertools,csv
f = "out.csv"
l1 = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
l2 = ['11', '22', '33', '44']
l3 = ['111', '222', '333']
headerNames = ['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3']
rows = itertools.zip_longest(l1, l2, l3, fillvalue=0)
with open(f, 'w', newline='') as resultFile:
    resultWriter = csv.writer(resultFile, delimiter=';')
    resultWriter.writerow(headerNames)
    resultWriter.writerows(rows)  # write all rows in a row :)
```

output file contains:

```
Name1;Name2;Name3
1;11;111
2;22;222
3;33;333
4;44;0
5;0;0
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! Since the lists have different lengths, the values 4, 5 and 44 are not written. Do you have any solution to overcome this issue?

Comment: @WesselJespers see my edit. I think that does what you want now